# How to make border to move upwards

Tags: html, css

```css
body {
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  height: 100vh;
  outline-offset: 5px;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 610px;
  width: 350px;
  transform: translateY(30px);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container"></div>
</body>
```

I want `.container` border to move upwards abit without carrying the other (`body`)border along

Comment: Didnt get the question, can you share what should look the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very clear...
What I'm understanding is:

- border red move upward?

you need to delete the transform: translateY(30px);

if you still want some space on top for the text, you add padding-top

```css
body {
  outline: 3px solid blue;
  height: 100vh;
  outline-offset: 5px;
}

.container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  height: 610px;
  width: 350px;
  padding-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet aspernatur assumenda consequatur cupiditate debitis eveniet expedita, facilis ipsa magnam maiores minima nam, necessitatibus nemo officia officiis quasi sapiente temporibus voluptas?</div>
  <div>A ab aliquam at dolore dolorum eaque earum eum impedit incidunt iure iusto laborum magni modi nesciunt nobis, placeat provident quaerat saepe veniam voluptate! Animi at consequuntur obcaecati recusandae sunt?</div>
</div>
```